# Error with branches in mercurial, what's wrong?

Tags: eclipse, graph, branch, tortoisehg, repo

I have a severe problem with my mercurial repository and I do not know what I have done wrong.
I am using the MercurialEclipse Addon for Java development on a local repository. Some time ago, I created some branches for better organization. 
When I then looked at the graph in TortoiseHg, it looked kind of wrong to me.

[image]

As I know, the graph of the main branch should always be at the left side. But in my case, it is shown somewhere else.

What have I done wrong? Commit error? Or do I understand the graph wrong and everything is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The left side are the parents of your current revision, with everything being in commit order (kind of sorted by date).

Well, if this isn't the standard, it's pretty common.

The `default` branch is **not** the `main` branch for everyone, as there is many ways to organize the code.